# Scaling an image to be the width of a custom view

Tags: android, android-bitmap

I'm working on a custom view that's giving me unexpected results. What I'm trying to make happen is to fill a picture the width of the view and scale it keeping its aspect ratio, but it's doing something weird...

Here's what my generated log is spitting out.

- View size: **768x942**
- Pic is portrait
- Original Size: 960x1280 Scaled: **768x768**
- Scaled bitmap: **768x768**

Now let me explain whats the log is saying according to the code. First we let the view `onMeasure` itself and once it's done that we're allowed to grab the width and height of the view. Next we check if the picture is landscape or portrait. Then we just do the math to find the size we need to scale to. After the math is done we create a new scaled bitmap with the results. The width is right but the height **should be 1024** not 768. I can't see where its messing up.

```
public void setBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
this.mOriginalBitmap = bmp;

if(mHasMeasured) {
    //Make sure the view has measured itself so we can grab the width and height
Log.d("", "View size: " + String.valueOf(this.mViewWidth)
+ "x" + String.valueOf(this.mViewHeight));

int reqWidth, reqHeight; //The required sizes we need

//Get the new sizes for the pic to fit in the view and keep aspect ratio
if(this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth() > this.mOriginalBitmap.getHeight()) {
//Landscape :/
Log.d("", "Pic is Landscape");


reqHeight = this.mViewHeight;

reqWidth = (this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth()
             / this.mOriginalBitmap.getHeight()) * reqHeight;

} else {
//Portrait :)
Log.d("", "Pic is portrait");

reqWidth = this.mViewWidth;

reqHeight = (this.mOriginalBitmap.getHeight()
             / this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth()) * reqWidth;

}




Log.d("", "Original Size: "
             + String.valueOf(mOriginalBitmap.getWidth()) + "x"
             + String.valueOf(mOriginalBitmap.getHeight())
             + " Scaled: " + String.valueOf(reqWidth)
             + "x" + String.valueOf(reqHeight) );

this.mBmpScaledForView = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mOriginalBitmap,
         reqWidth, reqHeight, false);

this.mSrc.top = 0;
this.mSrc.left = 0;
this.mSrc.right = this.mBmpScaledForView.getWidth();
this.mSrc.bottom = this.mBmpScaledForView.getHeight();
this.mDst = this.mSrc; 

Log.d("", "Scaled bitmap : "
             + String.valueOf(this.mBmpScaledForView.getWidth())
             + "x" + String.valueOf(this.mBmpScaledForView.getHeight()));

}
}
```

Comment: issue with integer division. `Bitmap.getHeight` returns an int, so `getHeight/getWidth` is 1, which causes `reqWidth == reqHeight`

Comment: Ah! Ok, so use a float then?

Comment: or simply reverse you operation : `reqHeight = (reqWidth * this.mOriginalBitmap.getHeight()) / this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth();`

Comment: Excellent! that fixed it! Please make an answer.

Comment: why do you use Bitmap.createScaledBitmap at all?  why dont you use a Matrix when drawing the Bitmap?

Comment: Originally I am using a maxtrix. I switched to createScaledBitmap while debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is with the image ratio computation. [Bitmap.getHeight()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getHeight%28%29) and `getWidth()` return ints, which makes the result of

```
(this.mOriginalBitmap.getHeight()
         / this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth())
```

be `1` for an image that is `960x1280`.

There are several options around this. You can make a `float` division by converting the return value of `getHeight()` and `getWidth()`:

```
((float) this.mOriginalBitmap.getHeight()
         / (float) this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth())
```

Or you can simply start by the multiplication :

```
reqHeight = (reqWidth * this.mOriginalBitmap.getHeight()) / this.mOriginalBitmap.getWidth();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.riktamtech.app.utils;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/**
 * ImageView that keeps aspect ratio when scaled
 */

public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {

    public CustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        try {
            Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
            if (drawable == null) {
                setMeasuredDimension(0, 0);
            } else {
                int measuredWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
                int measuredHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
                if (measuredHeight == 0 && measuredWidth == 0) { // Height and
                                                                    // width set
                                                                    // to
                                                                    // wrap_content
                    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
                } else if (measuredHeight == 0) { // Height set to wrap_content
                    int width = measuredWidth;
                    int height = width * drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()
                            / drawable.getIntrinsicWidth();
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                } else if (measuredWidth == 0) { // Width set to wrap_content
                    int height = measuredHeight;
                    int width = height * drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()
                            / drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
                } else { // Width and height are explicitly set (either to
                            // match_parent or to exact value)
                    setMeasuredDimension(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

}
```